# error C2065: 'MF_BITMAP' : undeclared identifier - Windows CE 6.0

Tags: windows-ce

I have added a bitmap in to menu in the following way,

```
HBITMAP bmSeparator = LoadBitmap(g_hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_LINE));
fOK = AppendMenu(hmenu, MF_BITMAP,IDM_LINE,(LPCTSTR)bmSeparator);
```

While compiling the code, I got the below error,

```
error C2065: 'MF_BITMAP' : undeclared identifier
```

is "MF_BITMAP" not available for Win CE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, MF_BITMAP is not supported for WinCE.  See the [documentation for AppendMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms936792.aspx).

Comment: Is there any other way to append bitmap as menu item?

Comment: You need to use the `MF_OWNERDRAW` flag and draw the bitmap/text yourself (See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee504295(v=winembedded.60).aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee502212(v=winembedded.60).aspx) for more info)